# What does the error "Write ECONNRESET" mean in general?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, econnreset

I'm working on a custom WebSocket server in node.js, and my client disconnected sending back the error; "write ECONNRESET".

I tried googling the error, but all the explanations and threads I found were vague and unclear. If I can know what the error means, I'm sure I'll be able to fix it, but I just can't find any explanation.

Can anyone provide some insight?